# Appending UUID in file name when streaming via StreamSets Data Collector

Tags: http, hadoop, client, streamsets

I am using HttpClient origin to stream a file from an HTTP url to Hadoop destination, but the file name in the destination is appended with some random uuid. I want the file name to be as it is from the source.

Example: source file name is README.txt , 
destination file name is README_112e5d4b-4d85-4764-ab81-1d7b6e0237b2.txt

I want the destination file name to be README.txt

I'll show you my configuration.

```
HTTP Client :

General

Name : HTTP Client 1

Description : 

On Record Error : Send to Error

HTTP

Resource URL : http://files.data.gouv.fr/sirene/README.txt

Headers : 

Mode : Streaming

Per-Status Actions

HTTP Statis Code : 500 | Action for status : Retry with exponential backoff |

Base Backoff Interval (ms) : 1000 | Max Retries : 10

HTTP Method : GET

Body Time Zone : UTC (UTC)

Request Transfert Encoding : BUFFERED

HTTP Compression : None

Connect Timeout : 0

Read Timeout : 0

Authentication Type : None

Use OAuth 2

Use Proxy

Max Batch Size (records) : 1000

Batch Wait Time (ms) : 2000

Pagination

Pagination Mode : None

TLS

UseTLS

Timeout Handling

Action for timeout : Retry immediately

Max Retries : 10

Data Format

Date Format : Text

Compression Format : None

Max Line Length : 1024

Use Custom Delimiter

Charset : UTF-8

Ignore Control Characters

Logging 

Enable Request Logging

Hadoop FS Destination :

General

Name : Hadoop FS 1

Description : Writing into HDFS

Stage Library : CDH 5.10.1

Produce Events

Required Fields

Preconditions

On Record Error : Send to Error

Output Files

File Type : Text Files

Files Prefix : README

File Suffix : txt

Directory in Header

Directory Template : /user/username/

Data Time Zone : UTC (UTC)

Time Basis : ${time:now()}

Max Records in File : 0

Max File Size (MB) : 0

Idle Timeout : ${1 * HOURS}

Compression Codec : None

Use Roll Attribute

Validate HDFS Permissions : ON

Skip file recovery

Late Records

Late Record Time Limit (secs) : ${1 * HOURS}

Late Record Handling : Send to error

Data Format

Data Format : Text

Text Field Path : /text

Record Separator : \n

On Missing Field : Report Error

Charset : UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a filename prefix and suffix, but it is not possible to remove the UUID.

In many circumstances, the *directory* is the smallest useful filesystem entity in Hadoop. Since files may be being written concurrently by multiple clients, and files may be 'rolled' (the current output file closed and a new file opened) for operational reasons such as file size passing a given threshold, Data Collector ensures that filenames are unique to avoid accidental data loss.

There is a workaround if you *really* want to do this: enable events on the Hadoop destination and use a [HDFS File Metadata Executor](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Executors/HDFSMetadata.html#concept_wgj_slk_fx)
 to rename the file. See this [case study on output file management](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Event_Handling/EventFramework-Title.html#concept_d1q_xl4_lx) for more.

Comment: Thanks @metadaddy. I have one more question, file content is duplicating from source to destination.
Assume Source file content is "SIRENE"
In destination file content is like 
SIRENE
SIRENE
SIRENE
.
.
.
Is there any configuration change that i need to do so that this don't happen.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you ask a new question, with the JSON export of your pipeline with all passwords etc removed?

Comment: By the way, we have StreamSets specific community channels - see https://streamsets.com/community